# What's the intonation pattern of "ideas"?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-english, phonology, intonation

The utterance of the [audio](https://mp3.fastupload.co/files/1624608366) is "But I need your ideas. I need two heads." The intonation pattern of "heads" completely goes down because the speaker's statement is finished. However, the intonation pattern of "ideas" doesn't seem to completely go down. It seems that there is a slight rise at the end of "ideas" since the utterance isn't finished. Does its intonation contour go like the picture shown below, which is a so-called tonic stress to have a continuation rise? Am I right about it?

[image]

Or, if there is only the first sentence - "I need your ideas". Is the intonation contour still same as the one with two sentences - "I need your ideas. I need two heads." ?

Comment: It sounds like PLAIN-RISE-FALL to me. She stressed the **de** syllable and the pitch goes up.

Comment: @Void So. it does go up at "as" slightly, at the end of idea, right?

Comment: I'd say it falls on *as*...

Comment: @Void. Then it completely goes down like "heads" in the second sentence. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I (plain) DE (rise) as (fall), so yeah it's almost the same as heads

Comment: @ Void Thanks. I got your point.

Comment: I don't think there's much of a rise on -de- (try pausing right after -de- - if there were rising intonation, it would sound like a question, but it doesn't). The syllable is overstressed and slightly lengthened, which gives it that "pleading" tone (like a child saying ***Moom**, I want to go to the **paa**-rty*).

Comment: Intonation pattern is not relevant to a single word. We call that **stress**, not intonation. You are not seeing the difference between a single word stress and the intonation of the entire sentence, which can take at least five different patterns.